# subprocess.call() does not return when using pydev

Tags: python, powershell, pydev

consider the simple python program below which runs a powershell script. It works fine if I start the python program from the command line, even though I feel it's odd it's printing a blank line for the return value instead of 0. However, if I run this python program from pydev, the script hangs after calling `subprocess.call()`. I'm using Pydev 2.7.0 under Eclipse SDK 4.2.1 under Windows 7. Python version is 2.7.3.

```
import subprocess

def run_powershell_script(script):
    cmd = ['powershell',
         '-ExecutionPolicy',
         'RemoteSigned',
         '-File',
         script]
    returncode = subprocess.call(cmd) 
    print "Done"
    return returncode

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print run_powershell_script("testscript.ps1")
```

The powershell script I'm testing with is very simple: it prints the path and then returns 0:

```
Write-Host "$env:Path"
exit 0
```

So to recap I guess I have two questions, the most important being why `subprocess.call()` hangs when I run this program under pydev and the other question is why when I print the `returncode` I get a blank line instead of 0.

Comment: I forgot to say something important and that is that I do see the output from the powershell script when I run the python program under pydev, but the subprocess.call() does not, in fact, return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% here, but doesn't `exit` just kill the script? To return a value when you exit to script, use `return`.. so Try this PS script instead:

```
Write-Host "$env:Path"
return 0
```

Comment: Ah, it works! It solved both problems, I get a proper return value and subprocess.call() doesn't hang. Thanks!